# categorising data in a pandas dataframe based on value

Tags: python, pandas

I frequently need to categorise a range of numbers:

For example:

```
|Num| cat|
| 2 |low |
| 7 | med|
| 10|high|
```

What I want! I want to build two functions.

**Function 1. -** Takes in 3 parameters:
    Parameter 1: dataframe name
    Parameter 2: a column name from a dataframe
    Parameter 3: a number of categories, for example I want (5).

This function will then work out the maximum, minimum, and return rages of values based on the fact I want 5 categories: (1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10).

I was thinking something like (max - min) / num categories, but somehow it would work out those ranges.

Then Function 1 would return the ranges, (1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10).

**Function 2.-** Would take in 3 parameters: 
    Parameter 1: dataframe nam
    Parameter 2: a column name from a pandas dataframe (same as in function 1) 
    Parameter 3. The name of the new column you want to create in the dataframe. 
    Parameter 4. a set of ranges from Function 1. 
    Parameter 5. And a list of categories, ['low','med','high'] etc

The function would then create the new column with the categories in it.

Comment: 1. Your question is unclear. What exactly do you want to do (which operations do you need your data structure to support)? 2. Why don't you just use dict?

Comment: Well `Def` certainly isn't going to work.

Comment: Do you just want to uniquely ID your categories and do this just once? If your categories can grow and the meaning can change i.e. you have dynamically expanding category where potentially more than 10 categories could be classified as low then you'd have to recategorise also which would make it slow

Comment: @EDCHUM the categories wouldnn't dynamically expand in that sense. Only in the sense that, If I want to categorise one column of numbers, I thought I would likely want to do this often, so why not create a function for it?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for [cut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 11, (10, )))

In [12]: s
Out[12]:
0     7
1    10
2     5
3     8
4     5
5     4
6     3
7     3
8     4
9     1
dtype: int64

In [13]: cat = pd.cut(s, [0, 9, 10])

In [14]: cat
Out[14]:
  (0, 9]
 (9, 10]
  (0, 9]
  (0, 9]
  (0, 9]
  (0, 9]
  (0, 9]
  (0, 9]
  (0, 9]
  (0, 9]
Levels (2): Index(['(0, 9]', '(9, 10]'], dtype=object)

In [15]: cat.labels
Out[15]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

And you either just map over the labels:

```
In [16]: map({0: 'low', 1: 'high'}.get, cat.labels)
Out[16]: ['low', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low']
```

or perhaps just change the levels (the names):

```
In [17]: cat.levels = ['low', 'high']

In [18]: cat
Out[18]:
  low
 high
  low
  low
  low
  low
  low
  low
  low
  low
Levels (2): Index(['low', 'high'], dtype=object)
```

*You can set this to a Series or column of a DataFrame.*

#### In fact, you can use the labels argument to get this directly:

```
In [21]: pd.cut(s, [0, 9, 10], labels=['low', 'high'])
```

Comment: Hi Guys, sorry from looking at the docs I have no idea what the CUT function does?

Comment: It splits the data into ranges, in this case (as I've passed 0, 9 and 10 it puts it into two groups: between 0 and 9, between 9 and 10.

Comment: where in "pd.cut(s, [0, 9, 10], labels=['low', 'high'])" do you define: range 1 (0-9), range 2 (9&10)? 

to me, 0, 9, 10 is only three numbers, not two separate ranges?

Comment: range 1 (low) 0 < x <= 9,  and range 2 (high) 9 <= x < 10. n numbers gives you n-1 ranges...